# gcc, static library, external assembly function becomes undefined symbol

Tags: linux, gcc, assembly, linker-errors

I have a problem with g++ building an application which links to a static library, where the latter shall contain some global functions written in external asm-files, compiled with yasm. So in the library, I have

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void __attribute__((cdecl)) interp1( char *pSrc );
extern void __attribute__((cdecl)) interp2( char *pSrc );

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

which I reference elsewhere inside the library. Then, there is the implementation in an asm-file, like this:

```
section .data
; (some data)
section .text
; (some text)

global _interp1
_interp1:
    ; (code ...)
    ret

global _interp2
_interp2:
    ; (code ...)
    ret
```

Compiling and Linking work fine for the library, I do

```
yasm -f elf32 -O2 -o interp.o interp.asm
```

and then

```
ar -rc libInterp.a objs1.o [...] objsN.o interp.o 
ranlib libInterp.a
```

Now finally, to link the library to the main application, I do

```
g++ -O4 -ffast-math -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -DARCH_X86 -fPIC -o ../bin/interp this.o that.o -lboost_thread -lpthread ./libInterp.a
```

and I get the errors

```
undefined reference to `interp1'
undefined reference to `interp2'
```

What am I doing wrong here? any help is appreciated.

Comment: Side note: -O4 does nothing for gcc/g++. -O3 is the highest level and probably always will be.

Comment: Not an answer, just a tip: if you're generating ELF files, it can be very informative to use `readelf` to look at what's actually in the object file.

In particular, `readelf -s` will show you the symbols the object file defines and references; symbols that are referred to, and need a definition from elsewhere, are marked as "UNDF". You may need to pass the `-W` flag as well, or else the listing will be truncated to fit within 80 columns, which can be confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the target type, gcc will not prepend a leading underscore to external symbols. It appears that this is the case in your scenario.

The simple fix is probably to remove the underscores from the names in your assembly file.

A couple alternatives you might consder might be to use something like one of the following macros for your symbols in the assembly file:

- from http://svn.xiph.org/trunk/oggdsf/src/lib/codecs/webm/libvpx/src/vpx_ports/x86_abi_support.asm

  ```
  ; sym()
  ; Return the proper symbol name for the target ABI.
  ;
  ; Certain ABIs, notably MS COFF and Darwin MACH-O, require that symbols
  ; with C linkage be prefixed with an underscore.
  ;
  %ifidn   __OUTPUT_FORMAT__,elf32
  %define sym(x) x
  %elifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__,elf64
  %define sym(x) x
  %elifidn __OUTPUT_FORMAT__,x64
  %define sym(x) x
  %else
  %define sym(x) _ %+ x
  %endif
  ```
- from http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~peter/otherstuff.html

  ```
  %macro public_c_symbol 1
  GLOBAL %1,_%1
  %1:
  _%1:
  %endmacro

  public_c_symbol my_external_proc:
      ; ...
      RET
  ```