# Problems compiling assembly file - Error: undefined reference to `function name'

Tags: c, assembly, compiler-errors

I am trying to take a look at a test program my professor gave us, but I am having trouble compiling it.  I am on Ubuntu 14.04.  I am compiling it with

```
gcc -Wall test.c AssemblyFunction.S -m32 -o test
```

I was having problems running the code on a 64-bit machine and read that adding -Wall and -m32 will allow it to work.  Doing that fixed the first problem I had, but now I am getting the **error: undefined reference to `addnumbersinAssembly'**.

Here is the C file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern int addnumbersinAssembly(int, int);
int main(void)
{

    int a, b;
    int  res;

    a = 5;
    b = 6;


    // Call the assembly function to add the numbers
    res = addnumbersinAssembly(a,b);
    printf("\nThe sum as computed in assembly is : %d", res);

    return(0);
}
```

And here is the assembly file

```
.global _addnumbersinAssembly
_addnumbersinAssembly:
    pushl   %ebp
    movl    %esp,%ebp


    movl 8(%ebp), %eax
    addl 12(%ebp), %eax    # Add the args


    movl    %ebp,%esp
    popl    %ebp
    ret
```

Thank you for your time.  I have been trying to figure this out for hours, so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that with GCC you are going to want to remove the `_` in your assembler file. So these lines:

```
.global _addnumbersinAssembly
_addnumbersinAssembly:
```

Should be:

```
.global addnumbersinAssembly
addnumbersinAssembly:
```

More information on this issue can be found in this StackOverflow [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3392582/gcc-static-library-external-assembly-function-becomes-undefined-symbol).

The `-m32` compile parameter is needed because the assembly code you have needs to be rewritten to support some 64 bit operations. In your case it was stack operations. The `-Wall` isn't needed to compile but it does turn on many more warnings.

Comment: Wow, thank you! What is the "_" for if you don't mind me asking.  Professor just told us to put it in, and didn't explain those header lines at all.

Comment: C Compilers often follow an old convention of automatically appending an underscore on global (non static) variables/functions to prevent name conflicts with C runtime library (the code that initializes memory sets up a running environment and executes your main() function). They didn't want people creating symbols in their `.c` that could replace (by accident) the basic code (variables and functions) that allows a C program to operate.